# How can I check if two polygons have an intersection on Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, intersection, polygons

How can I check if two polygons have an intersection on Google maps? I have to check if a postal_code is inside of a circle totally or partially. I only knew the path of polygons, and the circle and its center.

Comment: I usually use turfjs for these types of calculations.  Something like this may be what you are looking for.  http://turfjs.org/docs/#within.  You can also look at the source on github if you want to understand how the actual algo works. I would go that route if google maps doesn't have this functionality alright built somewhere in their api.

Comment: thanks it's what i'm looking for.I searched for this for while but i didn't find nothing. Really thank you.